# jQuery toggle( ) between two functions not working

Tags: jquery

ok so here is my code

HTML:

```
<div id="cta-end"><h1>Modification</h1></div>
<div id="bloc1"></div>
<div id="bloc2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#cta-end
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    text-align:center;
}

#cta-end:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
}

#bloc1, #bloc2
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    display:none;
}

#bloc1{
    background-color:blue;
}
#bloc2{
    background-color:grey;
}
```

and jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#cta-end').click(function(){   
          $('#cta-end').toggle(function () {
               $('#bloc1').css({"display":"block"});
               $('#bloc2').css({"display":"block"});
            },
               function () {
                  $('#bloc1').css({"display":"none"});
                  $('#bloc2').css({"display":"none"});
               }
               );
         });

   });
```

What I am trying to do, is that when `cta-end` is clicked, the two divs `bloc1` and `bloc2` display, and when i click another time on `cta-end` it displays none.
My code doesn't work at all. I guess I'm not using the `toggle()` function as it should be used.
I just want to switch the two functions any time `cta-end` is clicked..

here is the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dellwolf/g4Rw5/)

thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cta-end').click(function () {
        $('#bloc1, #bloc2').toggle();
        //or $('#bloc1, #bloc2').toggle(1000); for transition effect
    });
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE1**](http://jsfiddle.net/arulmr/5dK94/1/)</kbd> or <kbd>[**JSFIDDLE2**](http://jsfiddle.net/arulmr/5dK94/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

try this out ,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/GB5tf/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#cta-end').toggle(function () {
           $('#bloc1').css({"display":"block"});
           $('#bloc2').css({"display":"block"});
        },
           function () {
           $('#bloc1').css({"display":"none"});
           $('#bloc2').css({"display":"none"});
        }
     );
```

});

TRY to use like this

```
     $('#bloc1,#bloc2').css({"display":"block"});
```

**EDITED** 
For jQuery 1.9

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#cta-end').click(function(){   
         $('#bloc1').toggle('fast');
        $('#bloc2').toggle('fast');
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try , Below code .

```
$('.target').toggle();
```

With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements

Answer (score 1):

toggling between functions dont work in above jquery 1.7 , you can use toggleClass() instead.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_toggleclass